# Excel замена текста

Tags: c#, excel

Для замены текста использую

```
Excel.Range rng = ...
rng.Replace("один", "два",
            Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole,
            Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Но если в ячейке будет написано, например "ыыыы один", то замены не произойдёт.

Можно это как-то обойти?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole** - Match against the whole of the search text

Ищет совпадения с полным текстом в ячейке.

> **Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart** - Match against any part of the search text

Ищет совпадения с любой частью текста в ячейке.

> Можно это как-то обойти?

Использовать `Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart`

Неужели сложно было самому попробовать, там же всего два параметра!?